# adding jQuery event to Ajax Links in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

to add a jQuery event to an Ajax link in CakePHP I used the following way,

```
<?php echo $this->Js->link(TITLE, array('controller' => 'CONTROLLER', 'action' => 'ACTION'), array('update' => '#DIV_ID', 'class' => 'FixAjaxReload') ); ?>
```

which becomes a HTML link and the following JQuery

```
jQuery('a.FixAjaxReload').on('click', FUNCTION);
```

on the other hand I need to add an event to the link,

```
(function(){jQuery("body").on('click', 'a.FixAjaxReload', function(event){
        var linkTo = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer") > 0) {
            window.location.hash = '!' + linkTo.replace(window.baseUrl, '/');
        } else {
            window.history.pushState('', linkTo, linkTo);
        }
});})();
```

- I used the selector syntax in the second event, because the link might be loaded by ajax call
- I used the other syntax in the first event(i.e. didn't change the CakePHP way), because if I did the event will be called multiple times (no. of previous Ajax calls)

but some how they don't work together

any ideas???

thanks in advance

Comment: I find myself better working without helpers like `Js`. It may also save me some time in the future in case of a major change on CakePHP core. As I upgraded recently, I know for a fact that the Upgrade shell may forget to change some code. The Javascript helper was one that didn't get changed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help

I found the solution
I edit the Cake Engine as follow,
in JQueryEngineHelper file --> event function 
  I replaced "return false;" with "event.preventDefault();" 
the Problem wasn't conflict between the two syntax as I thought, It was the "return false;" statement preventing the next scripts from being executed

thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, as you exceed the basic requirements of the Javascript helper that is bundled with CakePHP, its best to remove use of the helper completely, and implement your javascript manually. The code produced by the frameworks JS helper is not complex, and can be reproduced and extended on easily.

Looking at your code example, it looks like you have a decent grasp on Javascript and jQuery, so this will be the best option for you.